# SELECT * with UNION ALL in Oracle

Tags: oracle, union-all

I have a requirement wherein I intend to fetch duplicate records from Oracle DB so as to mimic scenarios wherein we have duplicate records.

So, I decided on using `union_all`.

```
select column1 from tbl where rowid in (select rowid from  tbl where rownum<=5)
union all
select column1 from tbl where rowid in (select rowid from  tbl where rownum<=5)
order by column1;
--works
```

However, when trying to fetch all the columns,

```
select * from tbl where rowid in (select rowid from  tbl where rownum<=5)
union all
select * from tbl where rowid in (select rowid from  tbl where rownum<=5)
order by column1;
-- Doesn't work. Invalid identifier
```

Any suggestion on what is wrong here would be great help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
  select * from (
     select * from tbl where rowid in (select rowid from  tbl where rownum<=5)
     union all
     select * from tbl where rowid in (select rowid from  tbl where rownum<=5)
    )
   order by column1;
```

Or explicitly list the selected columns instead of using `select *`:

[Sorting Query Results](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries005.htm#SQLRF52348)

> For compound queries containing set operators UNION, INTERSECT,
>   MINUS, or UNION ALL, the ORDER BY clause must specify positions or
>   aliases rather than explicit expressions. Also, the ORDER BY clause
>   can appear only in the last component query. The ORDER BY clause
>   orders all rows returned by the entire compound query.

---

Comment: Thanks a lot for the prompt answer. Can you please explain what is the role of outer select * ?

Comment: By writing the outer select, you are creating an inline view of the union all results.